# python equivalent to java guava Preconditions

Tags: python

Does python have any equivalent to java Preconditions library. e.g.

in java, you can check the parameters like this:

```
public void dummymethod(Cat a, Dog b) {
   Preconditions.checkNotNull(a, "a can not be null.");
   Preconditions.checkNotNull(b, "b can not be null.");
   /**
   your logic
   **/   
}
```

If a or b is null, Java throws Runtime Exception, How about python, what's the best practice here for python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use `assert` to verify conditions, the best practice in Python is normally to document the behaviour of your function, and then let it fail if the preconditions are not met.

For example, if you were reading from a file, you would do something like:

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'rU') # allow IOError if file doesn't exist / invalid permissions
```

rather than testing for failure cases first.

Comment: Can you provide a reference where it indicates that this is a best practice for Python?

Answer (score 0):

Since I see you have passed strings. `assert` and checking for empty strings would be a way. See the following code.

```
>>> try:
        assert a is not ''
    except:
        #Do Something
```

Comment: Yes. Just found out about this. I don't know if OP is aiming for `.pyo` files. I should remove my answer in that case.